# Gradle "Couldn't replace placeholder" on build

Tags: java, gradle

I'm having a JavaFX project configured with Gradle in IntelliJ.
Whenever I'm trying to run `gradlew.bat clean build` or simply the `build` task directly from IntelliJ, this is what I receive:

```
> Task :startScripts FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':startScripts'.
> Couldn't replace placeholder in E:\git\yuber\build\scripts\yuber
```

I'm also using the `shadowJar` plugin, which actually works when I'm trying to create a `jar` file and run it. And it works perfectly. Although, I'm not sure why it won't build. Looked everywhere for an answer, but seems that no one actually had this problem at this moment?

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.yuber'
    mainClass = 'com.example.yuber.Launcher'
}

javafx {
    version = '11.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.0')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.3.2') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.1.13') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.2.0')
    implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')
    implementation('eu.hansolo:tilesfx:11.48') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220320'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openjfx.javafxplugin) to the latest version inside `build.gradle` (from **0.0.10**, as IntelliJ added it, to **0.0.13**) seemed to have fixed the problem.